# Trying to append a div to class, Whats wrong?

Tags: jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#button').click(function () {
        if ($('#newauthor') = !'' && $('#newquote') = !'') {
            var addAuthor = $('input[newauthor]').val();
            $(".allquotes").append("<div class = 'quotesbox'><p class = 'author'>" + addAuthor + "</p></div>");

            var addQuote = $('input[newquote]').val();
            $(".allquotes").append("<div class = 'quotesbox'><p class = 'author'>" + addQuote + "</p></div>");
        }
    }); 
});
```

I cant seem to figure it out. I'm trying to check to see if newauthor and newquote have something in them, then add them to the "allquotes' class. I'm new tothis site, so i don't really know proper question structure. *edit Any reasons why the click function wouldn't work? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xzrA3/)

Comment: It would be helpful if you attached your HTML, or even better: use http://jsfiddle.net/ to show us your full code.
I can see you have some syntax errors, but you have to tell us more if you want help

Answer (score 2):

Firstly you have the wrong syntax for **Not equal to**

`=! ''`  supposed to be    `!= ''`

Secondly $('#newauthor')  is a jQuery Object

So you need to check **for null** and not **empty string**

```
 if( !$('#newauthor') &&  !$('#newquote')){
```

If you want to check if the elements are there on the page or not

If you want to check the conditions on the text inside it..

Then for form elements use  `$(selector).val()`

Otherwise use               `$(selector).text()`

Answer (score 0):

If they are divs or some other kind of elements, and you are trying to figure out if newauthor and newquote have any text in them, you want

```
if ($('#newauthor').text() != '' && $('#newquote').text() != '') {
```

Because $('#newauthor') returns a jQuery object, which then has a bunch of methods you can use to do various things with, like getting the text contents. But it's hard to tell what newauthor and newquote are. If they are inputs, then you want

```
$("#newauthor").val() != '' && $("#newquote").val() != ""
```

inside of the if clause.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to rearrange a little, based on your fiddle:

```
$('#button').on('click', function(){
    var addAuthor= $('input[name=newauthor]').val();
    var addQuote= $('input[name=newquote]').val();
    if(addAuthor != '' && addQuote != ''){
        $(".allquotes").append("<div class = 'quotesbox'><p class = 'author'>" + addAuthor + "</p></div>");
        $(".allquotes").append("<div class = 'quotesbox'><p class = 'author'>" + addQuote + "</p></div>");
        };
})
```